# Comma delimited resultes in SQL using SUM(CASE WHEN

Tags: sql, oracle, count, case

I have the following SQL statement in my query and wanted to know how to write something very similar but instead of a count show me the actual matching item and list them in comma delimited form. I am using Oracle DB.

```
SUM(CASE WHEN b.item LIKE 'EU%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS EU_COUNT
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are looking for `listagg()`?

```
listagg(CASE WHEN b.item LIKE 'EU%' THEN b.item END, ',') within group (order by b.item)
```